# asp.net Multi tenant localization

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, multi-tenant

We are developing an asp.net core multi-tenant application in which we have a single installation of the software and, based on the host, it gets the data from different database. THis way each tenant has it own database.

```
Single application - multiple tenat databases
```

Since tenants can personalize the fixed texts of the application, we need to store those localizations resources in the tenant database. At the beggining we load those resources with the default values but after that each tenant could change those values.

We need a way to have those resources so when someone types www.tenant-01.com it gets the resources for this tenant. But accessing the database each time we need a resource is not a good technique since the performance would be horrible...

Any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: You probably could use [caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) and incorporate Request.Host.Host in your key.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more your idea? thanks

Comment: The use of caching would address your last issue regarding performance.  For the key you could use something like ```String.Format("{0}_{1}", Request.Host.Host, "name")``` where name is the resource and value is a localization like "Acme Corp" which is pulled from the DB.